# import cupy error: .../nvrtc.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: nvrtcGetNVVMSize, version libnvrtc.so.11.2

Tags: cupy

I'm using GTX2080 on Ubuntu 22.04
here's the output of `nvcc --version`:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jun__8_16:49:14_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.99
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31442593_0
```

so I installed cupy using:

```
pip install cupy-cuda117
```

However, when I run `import cupy` it returns an import error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupy/__init__.py:18, in <module>
     17 try:
---> 18     from cupy import _core  # NOQA
     19 except ImportError as e:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupy/_core/__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from cupy._core import core  # NOQA
      2 from cupy._core import fusion  # NOQA

File cupy/_core/core.pyx:1, in init cupy._core.core()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupy/cuda/__init__.py:8, in <module>
      7 from cupy._environment import get_hipcc_path  # NOQA
----> 8 from cupy.cuda import compiler  # NOQA
      9 from cupy.cuda import device  # NOQA

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupy/cuda/compiler.py:18, in <module>
     17 from cupy_backends.cuda.api import runtime
---> 18 from cupy_backends.cuda.libs import nvrtc
     19 from cupy import _util

ImportError: /home/sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupy_backends/cuda/libs/nvrtc.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: nvrtcGetNVVMSize, version libnvrtc.so.11.2

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import cupy

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupy/__init__.py:20, in <module>
     18     from cupy import _core  # NOQA
     19 except ImportError as e:
---> 20     raise ImportError(f'''
     21 ================================================================
     22 {_environment._diagnose_import_error()}
     23 
     24 Original error:
     25   {type(e).__name__}: {e}
     26 ================================================================
     27 ''') from e
     30 from cupy import cuda  # NOQA
     31 # Do not make `cupy.cupyx` available because it is confusing.

ImportError: 
================================================================
Failed to import CuPy.

If you installed CuPy via wheels (cupy-cudaXXX or cupy-rocm-X-X), make sure that the package matches with the version of CUDA or ROCm installed.

On Linux, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable depending on how you installed CUDA/ROCm.
On Windows, try setting CUDA_PATH environment variable.

Check the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

Original error:
  ImportError: /home/sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupy_backends/cuda/libs/nvrtc.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: nvrtcGetNVVMSize, version libnvrtc.so.11.2
================================================================
```

it says "On Linux, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable depending on how you installed CUDA/ROCm." I've edit the .bashrc file to include the path of cuda:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64\
                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

but still no luck, same import error. I tried reboot but same result... Thanks for any help!

Comment: After adding the variable to your .bashrc, did you start a new shell or re-sourced the .bashrc?

Comment: I start a new shell

Comment: Your `.bashrc` syntax seems wrong, try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"`.

Comment: Hi @kmaehashi I tried it but same error.

Comment: I copied the path from https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup

Comment: when I print the variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH/` it returns `bash: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/: Is a directory`

Comment: Could you try uninstalling `cupy-cuda117` (which is for CuPy v10 or earlier) and install `cupy-cuda11x` (a new package in CuPy v11)? https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html#installing-cupy

Comment: @kmaehashi it works! thanks! On the other hand, this "cupy-cuda11x" is really confusing, I thought I should replace 11x with cuda version such as 117. It would be better to add "literally 11x and not replace it with your cuda toolkit version" on the installation page, so people don't accidentally install cupy v10 or earlier.

Comment: @Sam-gege Sounds a good suggestion. I'll try fixing the docs to make that point clear.

Comment: @kmaehashi Could you please consider writing your comment as an answer to this post (maybe with a few more details)? To make it easier for others to find the solution.